# Cookie not showing (apache httpclient v4)

Tags: java, nginx, apache-httpclient-4.x

```
  private static CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
  private HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  private static HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "http://www.codechef.com";
    String account = "http://www.codechef.com/node?destination=node";
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    List<NameValuePair> postParams = http.getFormParams();
    sendPost(url, postParams);
  }

  private void sendPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> postParams) 
        throws Exception {

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    post.setHeader("Accept","text/plain");
    post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
    post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post,httpContext);

    List<Cookie> cook=cookieStore.getCookies();
    if(cook==null)
        System.out.println("Null");
    else{
        System.out.println(cook.size());
        for(Cookie c:cook){
            String cookieReader=c.getName()+" = "+c.getValue()+";domain= "+c.getDomain();
            System.out.println(cookieReader);
        }
    }

  }

  public List<NameValuePair> getFormParams() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    List<NameValuePair> paramList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    paramList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","name"));
    paramList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass","pass"));

    return paramList;
  }
```

After the post method, the size of the cookie is 0, but I checked from the browser, and it shows sessionID cookie. But I cannot extract it using this code to authenticate user. Thank you.

Comment: A place to start debugging might be to print 'response.getHeaders("cookie");' right after 'response' is received. Maybe even manually adding it to the CookieStore, and see if 'cookieStore.getCookies()' returns anything.

Comment: Also, when you check the headers received in your browser, make sure you don't confuse POST and GET (ie: POST might not return the same headers that a GET will return). You can insert a line printing out 'response.getHeaders("cookie");' to see the actual cookie-headers received.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention on the HTML form fields.
There is often hidden fields required in order to achieve the post process correctly.

Take at look the html source of the login form on this website (inspect element...)
The form fields are: "user", "pass" plus two hidden fields "form_build_id" and "form_id".

Try adding this in your 'getFormParams' function:

```
paramList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form_id","user_login_block"));
```